# Can't make file in YOLO

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am trying to do character recognition using YOLO. But when i try to make the file with

> GPU=1
>
> CUDNN=0
>
> CUDNN_HALF=0
>
> OPENCV=0
>
> AVX=0
>
> OPENMP=0
>
> LIBSO=0
>
> ZED_CAMERA=0

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and has GPU Nvidia Quadro P2000.
I had installed CUDA version 10.1 and has driver 430.40. When i try to make this file, i get the following error:-

> compilation terminated.
>
> Makefile:149: recipe for target 'obj/image_opencv.o' failed
>
> make: *** [obj/image_opencv.o] Error 1

How can i solve this error?